# Is line training (pay to fly) allowed in the USA?

Tags: flight-training, faa

In Europe some commercial airlines--such as Wizz Air and Air Berlin--charge licensed co-pilots to sit in the cockpit.

It is called "pay to fly" or "Line training".

Is it allowed in the USA ? Is there a FAA regulation regarding that?

Comment: I think GoJet did this a few years back but I don't have enough firsthand knowledge to post it as an answer.

Comment: Related: http://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/1736

Answer (score 3):

It is not prohibited in the US, but I don't think it's currently practiced anywhere.  There used to be a school called [Tab Express](http://www.nytimes.com/2009/07/05/business/05loan.html?pagewanted=all&_r=0) that did something like this, but the most notorious one was an airline called [Gulfstream International Airlines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silver_Airways) that operated as United Express in Florida.  Gulfstream is now operating as Silver Airways and, as far as I know, has discontinued the practice of having the FO pay to be there.